# Ordered List only generating the first bullet in my list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to do a simple ordered list for my page. For whatever reason I am only getting the first bullet in my list on my page, not sure why this is. HTML and CSS Code below, appreciate any help!

HTML:

```
{%  extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}



<br>
<br>

<div class='font1' align='left' style='font-size: 16px'>
 <p>Quote</p> 
<hr>
</div>



<div>
<ol>
  <li>Line Item 1</li>
  <li>Line Item 2</li>
</ol>
<div>





<!--{% include "personal/includes/htmlsnippet.html" %}-->
{% endblock %}
```

CSS:
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

```
p {
  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
}


.opensans {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

ol{
    list-style-type: circle;
    /* Let the element behave like a <li> element */   
    display:list-item; 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 50px;


}



.name{
 color: #3d3d70;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 2.5px solid black;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0; 
    width: 90%;

}

table {

  border: 4px solid white;
}


/* Navigation Bar */

ul {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    /* removes bullets */list-style-type: none;
    /* removes browser default settings */ margin: 0;
    background-color: 'white';
    text-align: center;




}


li {
    /* to get block elements to slide next to each other */

    display: inline-block;


}

li a {
    /* displays links as whole link area clickable blocks, can then specify padding (heigh, width, margins, etc) */
    display: inline-block;
    /* down, over*/
    padding: 20px 35px;
    background-color: 'white';
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.25vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;

}

li a:hover {
    /*color when hover over bar*/
    color: #8989dc;
    /* no underline when hovering over */
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.35vw;
    display: inline-block;

}

.active {
    /* to let user know which tab currently on */
    background-color: #8989dc;
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working fine for me**--

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

           <style type="text/css">
            ol{
    list-style-type: circle;
    /* Let the element behave like a <li> element */   
    display:list-item; 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 50px;


}
           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
         <div>
<ol>
  <li>Line Item 1</li>
  <li>Line Item 2</li>
</ol>
<div>
            </body>
```

Comment: Are you adding the style sheet properly try adding the css in the html itself between `<style></style>` inside `<head>` tag

Answer (score 0):

`<ol>` is an *ordered* list, i.e. one that puts auto-increasing numbers in front of the list items. To use `list-style-type: circle;` here doesn't really make sense. It seems like you want an unordered list - `<ul>`?